# failed to launch jenkins slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to setup a jenkins clusters on our servers. After configuring a slave node, then trying to launch that slave from the master, it failed to start.

error log

```
[07/03/17 11:12:19] [SSH] Checking java version of java
[07/03/17 11:12:19] [SSH] java -version returned 1.5.0.
[07/03/17 11:12:19] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[07/03/17 11:12:19] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...
[07/03/17 11:12:19] [SSH] Copied 717,563 bytes.
Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
[07/03/17 11:12:19] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/app/taiji/build/jenkins2" && java  -jar slave.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: hudson.remoting.Launcher (unrecognized class file version)
   at java.lang.VMClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(libgcj.so.10)
   at gnu.java.lang.MainThread.run(libgcj.so.10)
Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
[07/03/17 11:12:19] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[07/03/17 11:12:19] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

One thing I have noticed is that it seems to have problems with mismatching java versions.

It seems to return java version 1.5. but I have both checked slave and master server. It has currently Java 1.8 installed.

```
ldndsr000004921$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

the jenkins system environment as below:

[image]

Please advise?

Comment: Goddammit Jenkins, where's my lunch?

Comment: I'd say you are on the right track. My jenkins 2 agent start shows: java -version returned 1.8.0_121.  Are you running java -version as the ssh user?

Comment: yes, it is the same user, one thing I concern is that the JAVA_HOME variable that is configured  pointing java 8 version is set in `.profile`  so that it might now be loaded when it run through ssh, is there anyway to loa d  `profile` prior to execute slave.jar file. . @SteveMiskiewicz

Comment: I have tried to test my theory `ssh slaves_machine java -version`, this command returns `java version "1.5.0"` , so definitely the `.profile` is not loaded through ssh command.

Answer (score 0):

this is due to javPath is not setup properly. I was able to fix it by specifying javaPath to correct java version.

[image]

After setting up, the jenkins agent is able to start successfully as below

```
[07/04/17 03:18:56] [SSH] Starting sftp client.
[07/04/17 03:18:56] [SSH] Copying latest slave.jar...
[07/04/17 03:18:56] [SSH] Copied 717,563 bytes.
Expanded the channel window size to 4MB
[07/04/17 03:18:56] [SSH] Starting slave process: cd "/app/taiji/build/jenkins2" && /app/phoenix/jdk1.8.0_66/bin/java  -jar slave.jar
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Slave.jar version: 3.4.1
This is a Unix agent
Evacuated stdout
Agent successfully connected and online
```

Comment: another way is to set `Prefix Start Slave command` to load user profile settting before executing slave.jar launch command